# Is there a general formula for combinations with limited repetitions?

Tags: combinatorics

Say you have 7 balls of 4 unique colors: 3 blue, 2 red, 1 green and 1 yellow.

What formula would you use to calculate all the possible combinations of 3 balls?

If it was a permutation I know I could simply do: 7!/(3!2!), so I guess there might be some similar operation involved.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael notes, combinations are order-independent. There are many ways to approach the problem you've presented, but to me, careful counting seems the easiest.

We consider 3 cases:

1. All 3 balls are the same color - there is only one way this can happen (3 blues), so for this case, we've found **1** combination.
2. 2 balls are of one color, one of another - The two balls can be either red or blue, and the 1 ball can be anything else. Hence, there are $2\cdot3=\:$**6** ways this can happen.
3. All 3 balls are different colors - We simply choose which ball we don't want in the combo, which gives us **4** options.

So, our answer is $1+6+4=11$.

Comment: That was just an example, not the actual problem I am trying to solve :) what should I do when there are N balls, U unique colors, different limits for each color and K balls to pick?

Comment: There's no formula. You just got to count in an organized fashion (complementary counting can also help.)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as Cofficent of $ x^3 $  in the expansion of $$
(\;1+\,x\,+\,x^2\,+\,x^3\,)(\;1+\,x\,+\,x^2\,)(\;1+\,x\,)(\;1+\,x\,) $$
$$ =\;(\,1-\,2\,x^2-\,x^3\,)\,(1-x)^{-4} $$
$$ = {6\choose_3}\;-1\;-2.4 $$
$$ = 11$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I am not sure what you are doing but I would like to understand

Comment: It's generating function, a way of assigning numbers to powers, and computing combinations via expanding the resulting polynomials. It's an effective technique for computers and the like, but, generating functions tend to get large and hairy really fast.

Comment: Each bracket is called as block like 1st bracket is block of blue colour ball + means "or " power is number of that ball selected at any instance product indicate "and " so product of all bracket is selection from all blue , red , green , yellow in each bracket 1 is that colour ball is not selected. Total selection is 3 so number of ways we can get product as $x^3$ is coefficient of $x^3$in the expension.

Comment: In each block it's sum of simple GP sequence only and can be generalized to any count.